# 'TypeError: name.push is not a function' while pushing a string into an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a multi line string which I am trying to extract some information by splitting the string and push to some empty arrays. But I am having some `type error` while trying to push array. My code as below. I did some research in stack overflow and some suggestion is to put the array `[]` as dictionary `{}`. But I don't want any dictionary. Can someone help?

```js
< script >
  var str = `PP 0800 / 00 / XX: Units: 2: Total: 4.70 || 
  PP 0800 / 00 / XX: Units: 1: Total: 2.35 ||` //This is the multi line string

  var singleLine = str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""); //Converting multi line string into a single line
  var splittedArray = singleLine.split("||"); //splitting the string based on the symbol ||

  var name = []; //Initializing three empty arrays
  var unit = [];
  var total = [];
  for (i = 0; i < splittedArray.length - 1; i++) { //Looping through the splittedArray
    var furtherSplit = splittedArray[i].split(":"); //Splitting each array further based on the symbol :
    name.push(furtherSplit[0]); //This is where name, unit and total pushing into three separate arrays
    unit.push(furtherSplit[2]);
    total.push(furtherSplit[4]);
    //    alert(furtherSplit[0]); //This is showing the name correctly
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Help with what exactly?!

Comment: To push the items into the three empty arrays without the type error

Comment: `$i`? That's a PHP variable declaration (yes, valid in JS too, but, there's no variable declaration here). You're looking for `let` or `var`.

Comment: Even I gave `i` instead of `$i` also have the error. And yes, that is a typo from me since I am working with `php` as well. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @ChloeAnderson Just corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `var name` since it's reserved for the `window` scope and Quirks to `""` String.
In contrast, by using `const`, `let`, (instead of `var`) your variables are now instantiated and inside its own block scope (not `window`).
Also, when you do a for loop with `<` use just `length`, not `length - 1`

```js
const str = `PP 0800 / 00 / XX: Units: 2: Total: 4.70 || 
  PP 0800 / 00 / XX: Units: 1: Total: 2.35 ||`;

const lines = str.split(/\n/);
const name = []; 
const unit = [];
const total = [];

for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { 
  const parts = lines[i].replace("||", "").split(":");
  name.push(parts[0].trim()); 
  unit.push(parts[2].trim());
  total.push(parts[4].trim());
}

console.log(name, unit, total)
```

Comment: The OP's code should work (`$i` will get defined as a property of `window`), the only problem I see is `var name = [];` and that is because `name` is a *special* property of `window`, a **string** property.

Comment: @Titus: You are absolutely right. After I changed the variable name from `name` to something different, my original code works. But I wonder, how come the above answered code is working correct although there is a constant `name` declared? Is it because of it is a constant instead of variable?

Comment: @Anu Yes, variables defined using `const` or `let` are treated differently.

Comment: @Anu sorry I had to go shortly, yes, `name` is reserved into the window scope and Quirks to `""` . in contrast, by using `const`, `let`, (instead of `var`) your variables are now instantiated and inside its own block scope (not `window`). Also, when you do a for loop with `<` use just `length`, not `length - 1`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan May I know is there any particular reason behind why `length - 1` cannot use? Because for my case, I must limit the looping to `length - 1`

Comment: @Anu, try the above by using `-1`. You'll see that the last line is being not accounted. If you want to make it work using `length - 1` than use `<=`